# Interpreting results from a glmm (lmer) with multilevel and interaction fixed variables

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, multilevel-analysis, linear, glmm

I am running my GLMMs on R to test whether the effect of breed on the acoustic parameters of meows is dependent on sex levels (`sex*breed`) and to test whether the effect of emission context is influenced by breed levels (`breed*context`). The sex levels are M (male) and F (female), the context levels are B (brushing), I (isolation), F (food), the breed are mongrels (EU) and maine coons (MC).

For example, I run this full model

```r
full_FL <- lmer(Median_frequency_log ~ Sex + Breed + Context + 
                Sex*Breed + Breed*Context + (1|Cat_ID), 
                data = data)
```

I'm interested in the effects on response of the interactions terms, so `Sex*Breed` and `Breed*Context`.
I obtained from summary(full_FL) the following coefficients and I care and report only those of interactions:

```r
                    Estimate   Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)         6.325      0.133  18.346  47.445    0.000
SexM:BreedMC        0.211      0.236  16.313   0.894    0.384
BreedMC:ContextF    0.166      0.054 432.756   3.093    0.002
BreedMC:ContextI   -0.109      0.052 434.439  -2.093    0.037
```

I also run the `drop1` function to obtain the general p values of the predictors, thus

```r
round(as.data.frame(drop1(full_FL, test="Chisq")), 3)
```

and obtained this:

```r
                Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF   DenDF F value Pr(>F)
Sex:Breed      0.025   0.025     1  16.313   0.799  0.384
Breed:Context  1.010   0.505     2 433.615  16.467  0.000
```

Then I run post hoc pairwise comparison with `lsmeans` for both interactions:

1)

here nothing is significant, in agreement with p value of sex*breed above.

2)

```r
pairs(lsmeans(full_FL, ~ Breed * Context), adjust = "mvt")
```

: here I obtained some significant p values, namely:

```r
contrast    estimate     SE    df t.ratio p.value
EU B - EU I  -0.2469 0.0396 432.2  -6.230  <.0001
MC B - MC F  -0.2059 0.0400 434.9  -5.141  <.0001
MC B - MC I  -0.1377 0.0340 436.9  -4.050  0.0005
EU F - EU I  -0.2072 0.0300 433.9  -6.908  <.0001
```

So, I report in writing the overall p-value for the two interactions (0.384, < 0.001) obtained from `drop1`. But then I want to discover if the two breeds determined different effects on acoustic parameters within the same context's type. So, here I should consider the P values obtained from the post hoc, right? in  my case, if I looked for comparisons between the two breeds for the same context (such as MC-B vs EU-B, MC-I vs EU-I, etc.) none of the these p values were significant, but they were significant only for different type of contexts. So should I ignore these significant p values? Is this reasoning right?

But in the writing have I to report the p values obtained from the summary(full_FL)? Namely 0.002, the only significant p value and say that the f0 of meows emitted by Maine Coon in the food context were significantly higher (from model’s output: t value = 3.093, P value = 0.002) in respect to that emitted by mixed breed cats during brushing?

For some others acoustic parameters, I've obtained the overall P values > 0.05 (with `drop1`) for both interactions, > 0.05 also from the summary of the model, but when I run the *post hoc* I obtained some significant p values, for example:

```r
     contrast    estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
   M EU - M MC   0.3928 0.126 15.4   3.128  0.0310
```

So the general question is, which p values should I consider for my paper? Is it possible that even if general p-values are not significant for the interaction, post hoc tests report significant differences? if so, what should I report? If I want to investigate whether the effect of context on parameters is influenced by breed levels, does it make sense to consider pvalues obtained directly from the model output, since they compare different contexts?